# I am a Pakistani National traveling to Canada to study and will transit through schengen countries. Do I need transit visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, canada

My Canadian study permit request was approved and I have a visa in my passport for it.  My transit are in Frankfurt and Zurich.  Will I need a transit visa to transit through these countries.  Transit time is 2  hours and 3 hours.