# I am a Pakistani National traveling to Canada for study, will transit through Kuwait and Frankfurt Will I need a transit visa for Kuwait?

Tags: visas, transit, canada, pakistani-citizens, kuwait

My Canadian study permit was approved and I have a visa for it in my passport.  I have transit one in Kuwait and one in Frankfurt.  Will I need a transit visa for Kuwait? It's a one hour stop. Doha to Kuwait to Frankfurt to calgary
I believe my visa will be enough to transit through Frankfurt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am a Pakistani National traveling to Canada to study and will transit through schengen countries. Do I need transit visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101106/i-am-a-pakistani-national-traveling-to-canada-to-study-and-will-transit-through)      Why did you feel the need to repost the same question again ? The other query has links to answer your queries.

Comment: @DumbCoder: I don't think this is a duplicate of the one you propose, as this one asks specifically about Kuwait while the other question was marked as a duplicate of Schengen-related questions.  And since site policy is to ask multiple questions in separate posting, I would say that the OP is doing things correctly.

Comment: @DumbCoder "Do I need a transit visa in Kuwait?" is absolutely not a duplicate of "Do I need a Schengen transit visa?" How is that even remotely the same question? Please retract your close vote.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&DC=CA&DV=Canada&TC=KW%2cDE&TV=Kuwait%2cGermany&h=c4263cef134c18e34eb9b36e0ef6f65323befae), Kuwait allows Pakistani nationals to transit without visa, so long as they hold an onward ticket:

> **Transit - Kuwait (KW)**
>
> Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
> In case of transit connections beyond 8 hours, passengers must remain airside and be accommodated in the airport transit hotel.
>
> Warning: Passengers with an article-14 visa in their passport are not allowed to re-enter Kuwait with this visa even if it is still valid. The article-14 visa is an exit permit.